# Linux timer pending signal

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer

I am creating linux timer using timer_create with SIGEV_THREAD parameter.

Sometimes callback is called after I disarm timer and delete it. This causes segfault, because it tries to access deleted resources.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_delete.2.html

Linux manual says

> timer_delete() deletes the timer whose ID is given in timerid.  If
>   the timer was armed at the time of this call, it is disarmed before
>   being deleted. **The treatment of any pending signal generated by the
>   deleted timer is unspecified.**

That basically means that I don't really know whether the callback will be called or not and I don't have a way neither to cancel it nor to force pending signal to deliver before I clean up the resources.

```
class timer_wrapper
{
private:
    std::function<void()> callback_;
    timer_t timer_;

    static void timer_callback(sigval_t val)
    {
        static_cast<timer_wrapper*>(val.sival_ptr)->callback_();
    }
public:
    timer_wrapper(std::function<void()> callback, uint32_t interval_sec)
        : callback_(std::move(callback))
    {
        struct sigevent ev;
        ev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
        ev.sigev_signo = 0;
        ev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = this;
        ev.sigev_notify_function = &timer_wrapper::timer_callback;
        ev.sigev_notify_attributes = 0;
        timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ev, &timer_);

        struct itimerspec spec = {{0, 0}, {interval_sec, 0}};
        timer_settime(timer_, 0, &spec, nullptr);
    }

    ~timer_wrapper()
    {
        timer_delete(timer_);
    }
};
```

If timer_wrapper goes out of scope I expect callback will not get called anymore, however it's called sometimes and according to man this is expected behavior.

What is the suggested way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you checking the status of your resources in your sigev handler?

Comment: Perhaps you could set up a flag to check the status of the resource you're deleting?

Comment: no, how can I check it? I have a pointer which I get from sigval_t and I don't know whether it was deleted.

Comment: That's not easy :) I need a storage for flag. If I clean up resources I need to clean up storage for flag as well. I could clean it up in the callback, but I don't know whether it will be called or not. So either segfault or memory leak?

Comment: Why don't you post what you have in a MCVE form?

Comment: @Aram do you mean the code? Code is quite simple, but issue doesn't reproduce that often. I will update the topic.

Comment: added code example

Comment: One possibility could be adding a small delay after calling timer_delete(), using something non-polling, like a select(). Another could be keeping a fixed pool of timer_wrapper, thus avoiding allocation and destruction, and keeping an "armed" boolean flag. Instead of using the destructor you'd have a "shutdown" method. You could even do this in a lower-level class and introduce an higher-level one using its constructor/destructor to handle the lower one from the fixed pool.

Comment: It seems the way they try to mitigate the issue in [glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.27.9000/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_routines.c#L99-L106) is using  a global list of timers with checking timer existence in this list on every timer tick under the global mutex and timer_delete removing the timer from this list. Unfortunately, this is indeed does not help with nontrivial user-disposable resources without reimplementing the approach because in the end the user callback is invoked in a separate thread asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach to avoiding the event generated by a timer when deleting a timer created using [`timer_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), is to not avoid it at all. Instead, use a `volatile sig_atomic_t  disarmed = 0;` flag, and have the event function test the flag before it does anything else, and return immediately if `disarmed` is nonzero.

This way, you first set `disarmed`, then delete the timer.

(It would be even better to use atomic built-ins, either old-style `__sync_fetch_and_add(&disarmed, 0)` and `__sync_fetch_and_and(&disarmed, 0)`, or `__atomic_load_n(&disarmed, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)` and `__atomic_exchange_n(&disarmed, 0, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)`, to access the flag instead, to ensure the proper ordering.)

For `SIGEV_SIGNAL`, you can block the signal first (using [`pthread_sigmask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html)), delete the timer, check if the signal was raised during timer deletion using [`sigtimedwait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigtimedwait.2.html) with a zero timeout, and finally reinstate the old signal mask.

(I personally use a single POSIX realtime signal (`SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-0`, defined at compile time), and a min-heap keyed on the event time (with each heap slot containing the time and a reference to the custom timeout/event structure), to handle a large number of events, with a dedicated thread.)

Comment: This is simple enough, but it will work for single instance timer. where should I store this atomic flag if I have multiple instances? It should be either member flag (then we come to the same problem, flag is deleted as part of instance) or sort of container with atomic flags which requires mutex protection and makes this approach not that simple.

Comment: For SIGEV_SIGNAL I can also check for pending signals, but I am trying to find solution for SIGEV_THREAD. I will consider changing timer in case this doesn't work.

Comment: @incognito: Deleting the timer (using `timer_delete()`) must be a separate operation from deleting the object representing a timer in C++. When using `SIGEV_THREAD`, you need a grace period (of both CPU and wall clock time), to ensure that the C library did not create a new thread before the timer was deleted, but without the new thread getting time to run. Because there is no deterministic way of closing this race window, the proper solution is to use a dedicated thread and `SIGEV_SIGNAL` (with the signal blocked in all other threads).

Comment: @incognito: Note that you can easily "simulate" `SIGEV_THREAD` behaviour with your own dedicated thread handling `SIGEV_SIGNAL`, and avoid the race window entirely. The only problem/difficulty with a dedicated timer thread, is combining 'new timer' and 'cancel timer' handling with the timeout. In practice, rather than a signal, using `pthread_cond_timedwait()` on a request mutex and condition variable (to otherwise sleep to next timeout), tends to be more robust.

Comment: simulation might work, but it seems to be more heavy solution than standard. anyway, thanks. I was expecting standard solution for this, but looks like there is no solution, only hacks.

Comment: @incognito: I disagree. For example, timers are a limited resource. A process is justified to expect to have a couple, but requiring dozens or more is likely to be a problem. The "simulation" method has actually quite a few positives: you can specify the thread attributes, especially the stack size (which by default is so large it turns out to be the bottleneck in the number of possible concurrent threads). None of these are "hacks" in any sense I recognize, simply different approaches to a *group* of problems.